# MVC 4 Adding Chosen Plugin to Html.DropdownListFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen, html.dropdownlistfor

Need some help.  I will be having dropdowns, some will have a large selection, in my app.  So I have decided to give the chosen plugin a try.  I need some help setting it up.

- Currently I have chosen.jquery.js and .css, chosen.jquery.min.js and .css in my scripts/content directory.  Do I need others?
- I have them in my bundle config and have them in my view.

...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/chosen")    
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/gradients")
```

View Drop down and doc ready

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title,
    @ViewBag.CourseList as SelectList, " -- Select Course -- ", new { @class = "chzn-select" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
...
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.chzn-select').chosen();
    });
...
</script>
```

Currently getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on my $(document)

What else am I missing?

P.S. If you need more, just let me know.

Comment: Did you include jquery in your `_Layout.cshtml` file, maybe there is some version conflicting

Comment: The error would indicate that the plain-old jquery is not being loaded correctly. Make sure your bundles are set up correctly and inspect the loaded page in the browser to make sure that jquery is being loaded.

Comment: Did you just check on the network tab, if the bundled files are being loaded in the page??

Comment: I have the bundles being rendered in the `_Layout.cshtml` currently they are in a `@section Scripts {}` at the bottom.  Should they be somewhere else?

Comment: They seem to not be loaded

Answer (score 0):

Alright.  So my after looking through the networks I found that my scripts weren't being created.  And then I had some typos.  Whoo.  So much frustration over simple mistakes.

Thank you to @Hackerman for the bringing up the networks